# Need helping setting up Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

First things first, I'm on Windows 10 64bit. So I have Python 3.6 installed as well as Pygame(installed via .whl), however, when I go to execute my pygame, it brings up the console and nothing else. I don't see any errors in Geany and Geany reports that the code was compiled successfully.

[image: My output and code]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your given code into a text file and reproduce the problem.
A screen shot doesn't lend itself to cut&paste.

Comment: I apologize, until now I was certain that I had either messed up the environment path, or I was using the wrong build commands. I didn't even think that it was an issue with code indentation, because I'm following a tutorial word-for-word, but the fact that it spanned two pages messed me up.

Answer (score 2):

your call to `run_game()` is indented, which mean's it's inside the definition of `run_game` and isn't getting called.

Try out-denting it

```
def run_game():
    ....

run_game()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was all I needed! I'm just starting to learn python and I'm not 100% used to not having curly braces.